# TNS listner does not know SID error occured even the listner started and with tnsping statues also ok

Tags: java, sql, oracle

When i try to connect the database using sql developer it gives the below error,

```
ORA-12505 TNS:listner does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

But the sid is correct as i was able to connect to the database earlier. The services are up and running and i did a tnsping sidname which gives me ok status.

The same error is giving for all sid's which earlier work successfully. So i assume its something wrong with the tns listener. How to make the sql developer connect to the database back?

Comment: Are you able to connect from sqlplus?

Comment: Does `lsnrctl status` show what you expect? Are you actulayy giving the SID, or might ypu be putting the service name in the SID field?